# Plot Prediction Interval over Points

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Say that I have data like this:

```
pred = rnorm(100, 0.1*(1:100), 1)
interval_lower = pred - 1
interval_upper = pred + 1
sample_data <- data.frame(

  actual = rnorm(100, 0.1*(1:100), 2),
  pred = pred,
  interval_lower = interval_lower,
  interval_upper = interval_upper)
```

How would I generate a plot with the prediction intervals plotted over the predictions and the actual data, where the predictions are colored in red?

Can't even add points to the plot:

```
ggplot(data = sample_data) + geom_point(aes(x = 1:100, y = actual)) +
  +  geom_point(data = pred, colour = "red")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking but try this:

```
ggplot(data = sample_data, aes(x=1:100)) + 
    geom_point(aes(y = actual)) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = interval_lower, ymax = interval_upper), colour = "red") + 
    geom_point(aes(y=pred), colour='red')
```

In your code, the second call to `geom_point()` makes no sense because you are telling it that the source dataframe is `pred`, which is not a dataframe.  It is actually just a field in the main data frame of the plot, `sample_data`, which you have already defined and have told `ggplot` about.

Moving the `aes(x=1:100)` part to inside of the `ggplot()` call instead of having it in all of the `geom_point()` and `geom_errorbar()` calls just saves typing.